# Django and TinyMCE: NameError: name 'url' is not defined

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I am trying to get TinyMCE working in Django. Here is what I did:

- Using this package as a reference: [django-tinymce4-lite](https://github.com/romanvm/django-tinymce4-lite)
- Successfully ran `pip install django-tinymce4-lite`; package installs fine
- Added tinymce to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Then here it gets tricky:

```
Add tinymce.urls to urls.py for your project:

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    ...
]
```

When I do this, I get this error:

```
url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),  
NameError: name 'url' is not defined
```

I have tried the following:

- Restarting django
- Instead of placing this in my project's urls.py I have tried my app's urls.py
- I have tried to convert this to "*path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),*" because all other entries use 'path' and not 'url', but that didn't work either (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinymce.urls)
- I have tried [another tinymce plugin](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce)

None of this helped. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

As per the suggestions, I updated url to path. Now I have a new error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinymce.urls'
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This error made me doubt if I had installed the plugin correctly. But it seems I have:

```
pip install django-tinymce4-lite
Requirement already satisfied: django-tinymce4-lite in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: Django>=1.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from django-tinymce4-lite)
Requirement already satisfied: jsmin in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from django-tinymce4-lite)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Django>=1.8.0->django-tinymce4-lite)
```

Comment: Can you post all the content of `urls.py` file. I hope it contains `from django.conf.urls import url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using django 2.0 you should use `path` instead of `url`:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    ...
]
```

You can find more details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/).

Comment: Thanks, I changed it but now another error appears.

Comment: @user585936 do you use virtual environment? If yes you should activate it before using pip install command. Also do you add 'tinymce' to installed_app?

Comment: I use docker. I have added django-tinymce4-lite to my requirements.txt and I have added it to the installed_apps list in settings.py as well.

Comment: @user585936 here is same issue: https://github.com/romanvm/django-tinymce4-lite/issues/33 Try to check in traceback if correct python path using and if tinymce installed there.

Comment: Thanks. I must figure out how to sort this out in Docker. My initial error is at least resolved so let me mark this as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

is because he's using django 2 
According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/) you can use 
[path and re_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/) example :

```
from django.urls import path , re_path

urlpatterns = [
     path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),

    # or
    #path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),

]
```